# How can I make non-english snippet? (e.g use Korean language in snippet prefix)

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, non-english

in my `latex.json` file

```
{
    "LaTeX":{
    "prefix":"라텍",
    "body": ["\\LaTeX"],
    "description": "korean"
    },
    "LaTeX2":{
        "prefix":"latex",
        "body": ["\\LaTeX"],
        "description": "english"
        }
}
```

second snippet "Latex2" go well, but first snippet don't activate.

How can I make non-english snippet prefix in vscode?

Comment: you could file an issue at the repo, it should work for any Unicode characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to press `Ctrl+Space` (Windows) or `Ctrl+I` or `Alt+Escape` (Mac) after inputting several characters to trigger suggestions for non-ascii characters.